# Can I use hreflang tag in sitemap-index file?

Tags: sitemap, hreflang, xml-sitemap

I have a sitemapindex file with `sitemap` and `loc` elements.

Can I add `hreflang` attribute to this file, is that logical? Because sitemapindex contains only URLs to other sitemaps.

```xml
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>domain/en/sitemap-general.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>domain/en/sitemap-categories.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>domain/en/sitemap-brands.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>domain/en/sitemap-products-1.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>domain/en/sitemap-products-2.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>
            domain/en/sitemap-products-images-1.xml
        </loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>
            domain/en/sitemap-products-images-2.xml
        </loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Comment: What do you think it means? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a task to add **hreflang** to ALL sitemaps but I don't know should I do that for index file :/

Comment: I see. I would argue that *sitemap index* files aren’t *sitemaps*. -- Anyway, if you would add `hreflang` to the links in the sitemap index file, it would mean that the linked sitemap file is in that language -- something which is usually not useful to say, because a sitemap typically doesn’t contain content except URLs and language-agnostic metadata.